# What is the difference between the Jedi and Pylance language server?

Tags: pylance, language-server-protocol, python-language-server

I'm having difficulty understanding the differences between the Jedi and Pylance language servers. I want to use them to extract repository-related information, such as the location of a function definition and the project dependencies, using a language server client.

Could someone please clarify the distinctions between the two? I am interested in their features and key differences. I have spent a significant amount of time reviewing their repositories, but the information seems ambiguous and hard to navigate.

Comment: A fundamental difference you should know at the very beginning is that Pylance is not open sourced and not licensed to be used for non-Microsoft IDE https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.vscode-pylance/license Probably that alone can determine if you are able to use it for your goals.